# Why a factor of 2 appears in gasket force calculation in ASME section VIII div. 1 flange design?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

In mandatory appendix 2 of ASME section VIII div. 1 the following calculation is given for calculating minimum bolt load required for operating conditions of a flange joint i.e. , under internal pressure:

$W_{m1}=\pi/4\times G^2\times P+2b\times\pi G\times mP$

Where P is fluid pressure, G is gasket diameter, b is gasket contact width, m is gasket factor.

The first term is clearly understandable, it is hydrostatic pressure force.

The second term is gasket force required to maintain a leak proof joint. But it should have been $b\times\pi G\times mP$, because area of a thin annulus of diameter G and thickness b is just $\pi G \times b$ and not $\pi G \times 2b$.

Why there is the factor 2 in the second term?

Comment: Do you think the gasket has two sides???

Comment: Of course a gasket has two sides. But for gasket stress calculation we divide gasket force by only one face area i.e., $\pi G b$. This quantity should equal mP. So gasket force should be $\pi G b\times mP$.